# How to generate certificates and provisioning files for iPhone development in Windows

Tags: iphone, flash, cryptography, adobe

I would like to do some iPhone development from my Windows box using the Adobe iPhone packager. I get how to do pretty much everything except creating / obtaining the certificates and provisioning files needed to complete the packaging process. What is the easiest and quickest way to get up and running?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it on windows myself, but I believe you have to join the [iOS Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/), and then the generation of certificates and provisioning files are done online at 
http://developer.apple.com/